# Mysql how create call store function

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have stored function in MySql **balance()**.

I want to select users with balance > 100;

This works

```
select user, balance() from users where balance() > 100
```

This don't

```
select user, balance as b from users where b > 100
```

I don't want to call balance() twice. How to write query as in 1 example?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL extends the use of the `having` clause.  When there is no explicit `group by`, you can use it like a `where` with table aliases:

```
select user, balance() as b
from users
having b > 100;
```

One alternative approach is to use a subquery.  However, MySQL materializes subqueries, so that adds extra overhead.